# Emberjs controller target points to the wrong route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I have a **student route** and created a **student controller** for that route. In the route I have an action that I tried to trigger from the route using **this.get('target')** which for some unknown reason returns  the **index route** which is the wrong route. So calling the action throws an error that says nothing handled the action.  This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/gazelelafeda/1/edit)

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){ 
    this.route('student');
});

App.StudentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  
  actions: {
    
    callMe: function(){
      alert('hello');
    }
  }
});

App.StudentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  
  actions: {
    sendtoRoute: function(){
      
      console.log('the route is:', this.get('target') );
    }
  } 
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
     {{render 'student'}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id='student'>
     <button {{action 'sendtoRoute'}} > hit me </buton>
  </script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
  
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.js"></script>
  
 <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `controller.get('target')` points to the right context in your case.
From Ember's [docs on `Ember.Controller.target`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_target):

> It can also be set after a controller has been instantiated, for
>   instance when using the render helper in a template, or when a
>   controller is used as an itemController. In most cases the target
>   property will automatically be set to the logical consumer of actions
>   for the controller.

`{{render 'student'}}` is create `StudentView` with template 'student' and connects it to a new instance of `StudentController`, then render result to the parent's template (`index` in your case). It doesn't create/transit to `StudentRoute`, so there is no active instance of `StudentRoute` while client in `IndexRoute`. Thus, `StudentController.target` is pointing to parent context - `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Thanks I discovered that and was typing my answer only to submit it and see that you have already answered it.

Comment: Use this.store.createRecord instead of this.createRecord. :) Em.Route doesn't have that method.

Comment: :) You can always set option "pause on exceptions" in webkit-like browsers: http://screencloud.net/v/CM0M. It'll help to catch an error in script.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it caused be using **{{render 'student'}}** to render the student template inside application template. To solve it I changed it to **{{#link-to 'student'}}** and the right route was called.

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){ 
    this.route('student');
});

App.StudentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  
  actions: {
    
    callMe: function(){
      alert('hello');
    }
  }
});

App.StudentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  
  actions: {
    sendtoRoute: function(){
      
      console.log('the route is:', this.get('target') );
    }
  } 
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
     {{link-to 'Student' 'student'}}
    {{outlet}}
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id='student'>
     <button {{action 'sendtoRoute'}} > hit me </buton>
  </script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
  
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.js"></script>
  
 <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
```